# How to write HTML into a function?

Tags: python, html, file, python-2.7

I am practising inserting HTML code into a Python 2.7 function. Can someone please help give an answer for this question:

> Write a function that takes three arguments: the file name of the HTML
>   file, the title of the HTML document, and its content. The function
>   should write an HTML file based on the three arguments. View your file
>   in a browser.

I am inclined to think of just doing something like this:

```
filename = open("hello.html", "w")
titleAndContent = '''<html><content><title>"TitleTitle"</title><p>"Hi brah!"</p></content></html> '''
filename.write(titleAndContent)
filename.close()
```

but that's not putting it in a function. I am a bit confused about exactly what the question is asking me to execute.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to write a function, and pass variables into it. I used a regex in the adding in the title instead of replace(), as I wanted to leave you something to think about.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

def write_html(filename, title, content):

    # prepare the content... inject the title into the
    # content.

    content = re.sub(r'(?<=<title>").*?(?="</title>)', title, content)

    wfh = open(filename, 'w')
    wfh.write(content)
    wfh.close

if __name__ == '__main__':

    name = 'hello.html'
    title = "This is a terrible title!"
    content = '<html><content><title>"TitleTitle"</title>' \
              '<p>"Hi brah!"</p></content></html>'

    write_html(name, title, content)
```

Contents of HTML file:

```
$ cat hello.html 
<html><content><title>"This is a terrible title!"</title><p>"Hi brah!"</p></content></html>
```